# Both TFS and VSS on a Single Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs, visual-sourcesafe

We are a small development team working mostly on `Visual Studio`. Until recently, I was working from Office and we were using `VSS` for version control. Now, as I had to move to my native place, I am hundreds of miles apart from my team and I am using `TFS Online` to collaborate with the team. As the team is still working on VSS, there is always a problem when merging the codes from two different sources. 
So, what I wanted to know is, what do you suggest for us.
Is there any tool that can help us achieve this?
Is it possible for us to use both TFS and VSS as version controls on a single machine for the project, so that a member can get the latest from VSS and checkin into TFS Online and vice-versa ? 
Sorry for the naive question if it is, I am a noob. 
P.S: Bosses dont want to spend on `TFS Online` licenses. :)

Comment: How small a development team? VSO is free for 5 users

Comment: @MrHinsh, its a bit larger than that. About 15 people.

Comment: So VSO has been priced so that it is competitive with MSDN (within which it is included). If you have MSDN you pay nothing. If you have only Pro then you are needlessly paying for non-production environments.With MSDN you no longer need to licence any internal non-production server. This is almost always cheaper than buying win / sql / n'stuff for your internals.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible for the same Project / Solution to have different source control connection.

you could open 2 different solutions . i.e. the original on VSS and the copy on VSOnline and then manualy try and keep both solutions inline, but it would be a MANUAL Process.

Answer (score 1):

As VSS is no longer supported in any way you should use the built in TFS tools to migrate all of your data to TFS on-premises.

Once there you can put TFS on http or https and access if just like VSO.